# nsnumber memory managment

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

is this code correct to manage nsnumber? i'm not sure in number set more than once in this part :
btw, this code doesn't work, i don't seen maxCount and maxRate outside block. Is it normally? Usually i seen it in other part of code.

```
maxCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]]; 

__block NSNumber *maxCount = nil;
__block NSNumber *maxRate = nil;
// winned must have less rate in same count issues 
[rates enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSSortStable usingBlock:^(NSNumber *rateFromRatesList, NSNumber *count, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog (@"%@/%@ have rateFromRatesList:%@, count:%@, maxCount:%@, maxRate:%@",currentDestination.country,currentDestination.specific,rateFromRatesList,count,maxCount,maxRate);
        if ([maxCount intValue] <= [count intValue]) { 
            if ([maxCount intValue] == [count intValue]) {

             // we are update destination rate only if we find rate less than maxrate
              if ([maxRate doubleValue] > [rateFromRatesList doubleValue]) {
                   maxCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]]; 
                   maxRate = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[rateFromRatesList doubleValue]];
              }
            } else {
               // in oother case, just update to max count
               maxCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]]; 
               maxRate = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[rateFromRatesList doubleValue]];
            }                                 
      }
}];
```

this part of code working fine (is it bug in enumerateusingblock?:

```
                    int maxCount = 0;
                    double maxRate = 0;
                    // winned must have less rate in same count issues 
                    //[rates enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *rateFromRatesList, NSNumber *count, BOOL *stop) {

                    for (NSNumber *rateFromRatesList in [rates allKeys]) {
                        NSNumber *count = [rates objectForKey:rateFromRatesList];
                        NSLog (@"%@/%@ have rateFromRatesList:%@, count:%@, maxCount:%@, maxRate:%@",currentDestination.country,currentDestination.specific,rateFromRatesList,count,[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxCount],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:maxRate]);
                        if (maxCount <= [count intValue]) { 
                            if (maxCount == [count intValue]) {

                                // we are update destination rate only if we find rate less than maxrate
                                if (maxRate > [rateFromRatesList doubleValue]) {
                                    maxCount = [count intValue]; 
                                    maxRate = [rateFromRatesList doubleValue];
                                }
                            } else {
                                // in oother case, just update to max count
                                maxCount = [count intValue]; 
                                maxRate = [rateFromRatesList doubleValue];
                            }

                        }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

`maxCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]];`

you NSNumber is autoreleased, and will be automatically released at some later point in time. So when you assign again to `maxCount`, you don't have any leak.

`maxCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[count intValue]];`

This would be different if you used [[... alloc] initWith...] because in this case the objects you get are retained and you would be responsible to releasing them before assigning again to the variable that point to them.

Comment: but this code doesn't work, i don't see outside enumeration maxRate and maxCount (inside everything ok, it seen)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are leaking memory as they are autoreleased objects so you are good on that front. However instead of creating a new autoreleased object, you can directly do this –

```
maxCount = count;
```

#### Alternate approach

I think you should be able to achieve what you're trying to do with these two lines.

```
NSNumber * maxCount = [[rates allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
NSNumber * maxRate = [[rates allKeysForObject:maxCount] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"];
```

1. First line gets the max of all the counts that you have.
2. Second one retrieves the keys that have the max count and retrieves the max rate.

Comment: i have problem with using any key-value features like @max, @min e.t.c. When i do it with any autoreleased nsarray, i have leaked memory, which push my app to grow in memory. this is a reason why i'm looking to avoid it

Comment: @Alex I am not sure of it. If **Leaks** is indicating that your have a memory leak with that statement then you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you are assigning autoreleased objects to the count and maxCount. Shouldn't they be retained or copied?

Your code doesn't leak, but after finishing the block the NSNumber objects should quickly get deallocated.